# Activity always gets restarted if I try to open it from notification

Tags: android, android-activity

My application consists of only a single activity. I try to open it from background when user taps on notification. I expect that android will open existing activity, but it calls onDestroy of the existing activity and then onCreate for a new one

```
    val openInAppIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    openInAppIntent.action = OPEN_IN_APP_ACTION
    openInAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    val openInAppPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(context).run {
        addNextIntentWithParentStack(openInAppIntent)
        getPendingIntent(
            0, 
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            else
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
    }

    val builder
            = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, BACKGROUND_ACTIVITIES_CHANNEL)
            .setContentIntent(openInAppPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_text, activityName))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
```

The flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK worked well when I opened the activity from receiver but now it's not allowed. I tried to play with different flags but the system seems to ignore them (maybe I specify them incorrectly?)

Activity definition in manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.start.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/StartActivityTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        />
```

PS Reported bug into the google bug tracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217739496

Answer (score 0):

Can you try keeping the flag O in the pending intent

Comment: Not sure I clearly understand what you mean. If you mean to specify no flags (pass 0) to the pending intent then it does not help. Pending intent flags do not define behavior of the activity. Thanks for the suggestion anyway